# Thymeleaf jwt spring security

Tags: thymeleaf

Всем привет, есть такая проблема, у меня шаблонизатор thymeleaf с которого я отправляю форму на мой эндпоинт, все проходит удачно, но я включаю Spring Security ( на мой эндпоинт ) и теперь мне нужно отправить мою форму вместе с header в котором токен для авторизации, на этот эндпоинт. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать? как мне отправлять форму вместе с токеном ( в headers ) авторизации который должен прийти на этот эндпоинт

Comment: А что вы уже пытались предпринять?

Comment: По сути я достиг желаемого через API джава скрипта ( XMLHttpRequest() ) могу отправлять хедеры с токеном на мой эндпоинт и получать доступ.
Но не могу прикрутить его к моей thymeleaf форме.
Вообще я ищу какой то способ реализовать отправку своей  формы на прямую из таймлифа на мой контроллер без того что бы нужно было прикручивать что либо, как то задать http header в thymeleaf и что бы этот хедер с моей формой на ендпоинт шел, не знаю возможно ли такое вообще, я просто слаб в тонкостях фронтенда и почти никогда его не трогал